# Saving .h file in /usr/include

Tags: sublimetext2, ubuntu-12.04, gedit

I recently wrote my own `.h` file which I want to be able to include in any of my future projects. Thus, I saved the `.h` file in the `/usr/include` directory and have been able to compile my C++ projects fine. However, when I try to make changes to the `.h` file in any text editor (Sublime, gedit) I am unable to save. I assume this is because the text editors do not have sudo root privileges enabled by default. So how can I go about saving changes to my `.h` file from a text editor?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should not save your own project files in `/usr/lib/include` as this is reversed for Linux distribution installed include files only.

Instead, pass an option to your gcc compiler to tell where to find your include files for your own project. Do this into your own project folder and home folder, so no sudo priviledges needed.

Comment: Alright. I'll change that. Right now I'm moved my testing.h file to a directory entitled 'MyProjects'. In my Makefile I've included a command: CXXFLAGS=-I/~/Documents/MyProjects/testing.h but this gives me a 'no such file or directory' error for 'testing.h'. Is this the right command? Thanks!